# iTunes: How to prevent a purchased gigantic app/book from ever downloading?

Tags: applications, data-transfer, itunes-store

In iTunes, I have purchased some apps and books that are very large in size.

I only purchased them in order to own them, taking advantage of a temporary low price, but I don't plan to use them any time soon.

My internet connection is not very fast and those downloads would take hours.

After purchasing I stopped the download but iTunes will try to download them again when it finds a chance to do so.

I have even deleted the downloads from the downloading list.

But every once in a while iTunes begins to download these gigantic apps/books again.

How can I tell iTunes not to download these purchases EVER unless I explicitly tell otherwise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seem to be to stubbornly cancel the download every time you see it happening. After many times, somewhere in the Big Apple Mother Ship a sentient entity decided to stop trying.

Answer (score 1):

Email iTunes Customer Support - http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/

Request them to 'clear your iTunes download queue'.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just letting them download overnight. It'll take a couple of days to get iTunes support to clear the download queue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the iTunes Settings (CMD-,) > Store dialog. There are two options at the top:

- Check for new downloads automatically
- Download pre-purchased items automatically

Comment: It will keep adding newly purchased items to the downloads queue no matter what settings you have, until they are downloaded.